# What triggers yawning for some people during physical activity

Tags: exercise, breathing

When exercising, oxygen demand increases.  Heart rate increases, breathing rate increases, and depth of breaths increases.  Some people experience yawning during exercise.  What reasons would that happen, or what is its purpose if only some people experience it?

I have looked and found a variety of theories, like cooling the brain, but can't seem to find a good source for what has the strongest evidence. This article for example only touches on some theories: https://www.health.harvard.edu/newsletter_article/By_the_way_doctor_Why_do_I_yawn_when_I_exercise

Comment: Welcome @TheSmallestOne. I understand your question, but I will edit this because otherwise, this will end up being closed as a medical advice request - and this question as you put it could not be answered adequately by anyone except a doctor who evaluates you.  And you do need to see a doctor for abnormal signs/symptoms that occur when exercising, even just to rule out rare conditions or need for further evaluation.

Comment: Please check out how I changed it to see how to frame a question for this site.  Feel free to revert to your question, but it may be closed due to site guidelines.  Also check this meta:  https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-long-can-this-site-be-popular-if-everybody-is-asked-to-see-a-doctor